# What are the reserved keywords in Elm?

Tags: elm

Every once in a while you get a compiler error like this:

```
It looks like the keyword `port` is being used as a variable.
```

That's annoying. Is there a complete official list of these keywords? I've gotten as far as finding [where the error messages are generated](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/e9cfb680b1cddc80268ae15262b2389a2a852fc6/src/Reporting/Error/Syntax.hs), but I couldn't find where the keywords are actually defined.

Meanwhile, here's a probably incomplete or incorrect list of keywords I found by browsing the [syntax](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax) page and trying keywords in the repl:

- let
- in
- where
- module
- exposing
- type
- port
- import
- infixr
- as
- if
- else
- then

Comment: Don't know if any such list, but then again, I find it much easier that the compiler does the lookup for me. Saves me going through some list manually to find out if my variable name happens to be a reserved keyword.

Comment: @wintvelt I agree the compiler is good enough for regular development, but when developing a code generator you need to sanitize input before the code reaches the compiler.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren, I have found the right list. You must reconsider the right answer!

Comment: @lifebalance i've considered it and i won't change my accepted answer as that was the answer which helped me. Moreover i think that your answer is referring to the same source, it's just that the file has moved (and dotcs's link has since gone stale). I therefore think a more correct approach would be to edit the first answer with a fixed link and updated list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [elm-compiler source code](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler) the [list of reserved keywords](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/master/src/Parse/Primitives.hs#L364-L375) is:

```
keywords =
  Set.fromList
    [ "if", "then", "else"
    , "case", "of"
    , "let", "in"
    , "type"
    , "module", "where"
    , "import", "exposing"
    , "as"
    , "port"
    ]
```

Edit:
There are actually some more keywords (found by [searching for "reserved"](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=reserved) in the repo)
I've found: `infix`, `infixl`, `infixr`. `infixr` has also be noted by the OP.

Comment: "where" is probably not one of those (Elm doesn't have `... where ... = ...` syntax, only `let ... = ... in ...`

Comment: @dotcs `infix` is not a reserved word. You can type `f(infix) = 2 * infix` and it works fine.

Comment: @MartinJaniczek `where` is definitely a reserved word. Try typing `f(where) = 2 * where` in the REPL and look at the error.

Comment: @RayToal type `infix = 3` in the repl, and it complains!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @oustad (on elmslack), the correct list can be had [here](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/d07679322ef5d71de1bd2b987ddc660a85599b87/compiler/src/Parse/Primitives/Keyword.hs#L3-L12) and it contains all the reserved words (including `where` and `infix`).

```
module Parse.Primitives.Keyword
  ( type_, alias_, port_
  , if_, then_, else_
  , case_, of_
  , let_, in_
  , infix_, left_, right_, non_
  , module_, import_, exposing_, as_, where_, effect_
  , command_, subscription_
  , jsonTrue, jsonFalse, jsonNull
  )
```